# jQuery not working in IE6 and IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Can anyone help me to figure out why my code is not working in IE6 and IE&. I believe it has something to do with the compressed.js or the slideshow jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a { text-decoration:none }
</style>
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ParaStyle.css">    
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie6-only2.css" />  
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only2.css" />
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Wrapper">
<ul id="slideshow">
  <li>
        <h3>Service Regulators
        <br><font size=2 color=#50658D>Domestic 496</font></h3>
        <span>Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Sensus/Service_Regulators_Domestic_496.gif</span>
        <p><br>Sensus Model 496 domestic service regulators can be used on both residential and small 
        commercial and industrial applications. The regulator is available with a variety of body 
        sizes, loading springs, and orifices sizes. The 4" roll-out diaphragm provides exceptional 
        performance, and provides capacities that normally require 6" diaphragm regulators. An 
        internal relief valve is a standard feature in the model 496. 
        <br><br>The Sensus Model 496 was previously manufactured as the Sensus Model 043-B.
        <br><br><br>
        <b><font color=#494A4A>Printable Literature</font></b>
        <br><br>Data Sheets
        <br><br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=469" target="_blank"><font color=#ACB0C3><b>Model 496 Technical Data (TD-1307)</font></b></a>
        <br><br>Installation Recommendations
        <br><br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=439" target="_blank"><font color=#ACB0C3><b>General Safety Instruction for Gas Regulators (RM-1399)</font></a>
        <br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=470" target="_blank"><font color=#ACB0C3>Model 496 & 61R2 Installation and Maintenance (RM-1307)</font>  </b></a>
        </p>
        <a href="#"><img src="Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Sensus/thumbnails/Service_Regulators_Domestic_496_Thumbnail.gif" title="Service Regulators Domestic 496" alt="blue" /></a>
    </li>   
    <li>
        <h3>Self Operated Regulators
        <br><font size=2 color=#50658D>Medium Pressure</font></h3>
        <span>Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Sensus/Medium_Pressure.gif</span>
        <p><br>The Model 461-57S and Model 441-57S are spring-operated regulators that incorporate a 
        "roll-out" diaphragm which approximates the performance of a pilot-operated regulator. The 
        roll-out diaphragm makes this exceptional performance possible because its action reduces 
        "droop" to a minimum. By offering near pilot-operated performance without a pilot, the 57S 
        regulators offer the advantages of simplicity, dependability, freedom from freeze-up, and 
        exceptionally fast response.
        <br><br>
        Both models are perfect for most intermediate and large capacity applications including gas 
        distribution systems, district regulator sets, city gate stations, town border stations, 
        monitoring, and a wide variety of industrial applications. These workhorses of the industry 
        have provided dependable service for over 60 years.
        <br><br><br>
        <b><font color=#494A4A>Printable Literature</font></b>
        <br><br>Data Sheets
        <br><br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=393" target="_blank"><font color=#ACB0C3><b>Model 441-57S Regulator Bulletin (R-1360)</font></a>
        <br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=391" target="_blank"><font color=#ACB0C3>Model 461-57S Regulator Bulletin (R-1331)</font></b></a>
        <br><br>Parts List
        <br><br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=394" target="_blank"><font color=#ACB0C3><b>Model 441-57S Parts List (RP-1360)</font></b></a>
        <br><br>Installation Recommendations
        <br><br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=439"><font color=#ACB0C3><b>General Safety Instruction for Gas Regulators (RM-1399)</font></a>
        <br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=395" target="_blank"><font color=#ACB0C3>Model 441-57S Installation & Maintenance (RM-1360)</font></a>
        <br><a href="http://www.sensus.com/Module/Catalog/File?id=392" target="_blank"><font color=#ACB0C3>Model 461-57S Installation & Maintenance (RM-1331)</font></b></a>
        </p>
        <a href="#"><img src="Parts_by_Man_OK_By_Jon/Sensus/thumbnails/Medium_Pressure_Thumbnail.gif" title="Medium Pressure" alt="purple" /></a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="fullsize">
        <div id="imgprev" class="imgnav" title="Previous Image"></div>
        <div id="imglink"></div>
        <div id="imgnext" class="imgnav" title="Next Image"></div>
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div id="information">
            <h3></h3>
            <h4></h4>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnails">
        <div id="slideleft" title="Slide Left"></div>
        <div id="slidearea">
            <div id="slider"></div>
        <div id="information2">
            <h6></h6>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slideright" title="Slide Right"></div>

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slideshow').style.display='none';
$('wrapper').style.display='block';
var slideshow=new TINY.slideshow("#slideshow");
window.onload=function(){
    slideshow.auto=true;
    slideshow.speed=5;
    slideshow.info="information";
    slideshow.thumbs="slider";
    slideshow.left="slideleft";
    slideshow.right="slideright";
    slideshow.scrollSpeed=4;
    slideshow.spacing=5;
    slideshow.active="#fff";
        slideshow.init("slideshow","image");
    }
$(function() {
    $('.rollover').hover(function() {
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
        $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
    }, function() {
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
        $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
});
});

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

includes.js:

```
// Google Analytics
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7328693-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
// Site Wide Navigation
var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;
function dropdown_open()
{   dropdown_canceltimer();
dropdown_close();
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');}
function dropdown_close()
{   if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}
function dropdown_timer()
{   closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}
function dropdown_canceltimer()
{   if(closetimer)
{   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
    closetimer = null;}}
$(document).ready(function()
{   $('#dropdown > li').bind('mouseover', dropdown_open);
$('#dropdown > li').bind('mouseout',  dropdown_timer);});
document.onmouseout = dropdown_close;
```

// Compress.js

```
var TINY={};function $(i){return document.getElementById(i)}function $$(e,p){p=p||document;returnp.getElementsByTagName(e)}TINY.slideshow=function(n){this.infoSpeed=this.imgSpeed=this.speed=1;this.thumbOpacity=this.navHover=100;this.navOpaci=25;this.scrollSpeed=5;this.letterbox='#000';this.n=n;this.c=0;this.a=[]};TINY.slideshow.prototype={init:function(s,z,b,f,q){s=$(s);var m=$$('li',s),i=0,w=0;this.l=m.length;this.q=$(q);this.f=$(z);this.r=$(this.info);this.o=parseInt(TINY.style.val(z,'width'));if(this.thumbs){var u=$(this.left),r=$(this.right);u.onmouseover=new Function('TINY.scroll.init("'+this.thumbs+'",-1,'+this.scrollSpeed+')');u.onmouseout=r.onmouseout=new Function('TINY.scroll.cl("'+this.thumbs+'")');r.onmouseover=new Function('TINY.scroll.init("'+this.thumbs+'",1,'+this.scrollSpeed+')');this.p=$(this.thumbs)}for(i;i<this.l;i++){this.a[i]={};var h=m[i],a=this.a[i];a.t=$$('h3',h)[0].innerHTML;a.d=$$('p',h)[0].innerHTML;a.l=$$('a',h)[0]?$$('a',h)[0].href:'';a.p=$$('span',h)[0].innerHTML;if(this.thumbs){var g=$$('img',h)[0];this.p.appendChild(g);w+=parseInt(g.offsetWidth);if(i!=this.l-1){g.style.marginRight=this.spacing+'px';w+=this.spacing}this.p.style.width=w+'px';g.style.opacity=this.thumbOpacity/100;g.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+this.thumbOpacity+')';g.onmouseover=new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,100,5)');g.onmouseout=new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,'+this.thumbOpacity+',5)');g.onclick=new Function(this.n+'.pr('+i+',1)')}}if(b&&f){b=$(b);f=$(f);b.style.opacity=f.style.opacity=this.navOpacity/100;b.style.filter=f.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+this.navOpacity+')';b.onmouseover=f.onmouseover=new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,'+this.navHover+',5)');b.onmouseout=f.onmouseout=new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,'+this.navOpacity+',5)');b.onclick=new Function(this.n+'.mv(-1,1)');f.onclick=new Function(this.n+'.mv(1,1)')}this.auto?this.is(0,0):this.is(0,1)},mv:function(d,c){var t=this.c+d;this.c=t=t<0?this.l-1:t>this.l-1?0:t;this.pr(t,c)},pr:function(t,c){clearTimeout(this.lt);if(c){clearTimeout(this.at)}this.c=t;this.is(t,c)},is:function(s,c){if(this.info){TINY.height.set(this.r,1,this.infoSpeed/2,-1)}var i=new Image();i.style.opacity=0;i.style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)';this.i=i;i.onload=new Function(this.n+'.le('+s+','+c+')');i.src=this.a[s].p;if(this.thumbs){var a=$$('img',this.p),l=a.length,x=0;for(x;x<l;x++){a[x].style.borderColor=x!=s?'':this.active}}},le:function(s,c){this.f.appendChild(this.i);var w=this.o-parseInt(this.i.offsetWidth);if(w>0){var l=Math.floor(w/2);this.i.style.borderLeft=l+'px solid '+this.letterbox;this.i.style.borderRight=(w-l)+'px solid '+this.letterbox}TINY.alpha.set(this.i,100,this.imgSpeed);var n=new Function(this.n+'.nf('+s+')');this.lt=setTimeout(n,this.imgSpeed*100);if(!c){this.at=setTimeout(new Function(this.n+'.mv(1,0)'),this.speed*1000)}if(this.a[s].l!=''){this.q.onclick=new Function('window.location="'+this.a[s].l+'"');this.q.onmouseover=new Function('this.className="'+this.link+'"');this.q.onmouseout=new Function('this.className=""');this.q.style.cursor='pointer'}else{this.q.onclick=this.q.onmouseover=null;this.q.style.cursor='default'}var m=$$('img',this.f);if(m.length>2){this.f.removeChild(m[0])}},nf:function(s){if(this.info){s=this.a[s];$$('h3',this.r)[0].innerHTML=s.t;$$('p',this.r)[0].innerHTML=s.d;this.r.style.height='auto';var h=parseInt(this.r.offsetHeight);this.r.style.height=0;TINY.height.set(this.r,h,this.infoSpeed,0)}}};TINY.scroll=function(){return{init:function(e,d,s){e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e);var p=e.style.left||TINY.style.val(e,'left');e.style.left=p;var l=d==1?parseInt(e.offsetWidth)-parseInt(e.parentNode.offsetWidth):0;e.si=setInterval(function(){TINY.scroll.mv(e,l,d,s)},20)},mv:function(e,l,d,s){var c=parseInt(e.style.left);if(c==l){TINY.scroll.cl(e)}else{var i=Math.abs(l+c);i=i<s?i:s;var n=c-i*d;e.style.left=n+'px'}},cl:function(e){e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e);clearInterval(e.si)}}}();TINY.height=function(){return{set:function(e,h,s,d){e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e);var oh=e.offsetHeight,ho=e.style.height||TINY.style.val(e,'height');ho=oh-parseInt(ho);var hd=oh-ho>h?-1:1;clearInterval(e.si);e.si=setInterval(function(){TINY.height.tw(e,h,ho,hd,s)},20)},tw:function(e,h,ho,hd,s){var oh=e.offsetHeight-ho;if(oh==h){clearInterval(e.si)}else{if(oh!=h){e.style.height=oh+(Math.ceil(Math.abs(h-oh)/s)*hd)+'px'}}}}}();TINY.alpha=function(){return{set:function(e,a,s){e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e);var o=e.style.opacity||TINY.style.val(e,'opacity'),d=a>o*100?1:-1;e.style.opacity=o;clearInterval(e.ai);e.ai=setInterval(function(){TINY.alpha.tw(e,a,d,s)},20)},tw:function(e,a,d,s){var o=Math.round(e.style.opacity*100);if(o==a){clearInterval(e.ai)}else{var n=o+Math.ceil(Math.abs(a-o)/s)*d;e.style.opacity=n/100;e.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+n+')'}}}}();TINY.style=function(){return{val:function(e,p){e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e);return e.currentStyle?e.currentStyle[p]:document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e,null).getPropertyValue(p)}}}();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is not be loaded.

Edit this line to fix this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1   /jquery.min.js"></script>
```

remove the whitespace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

At the very bottom of your page, add the following code to see if jQuery is loaded or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( jQuery ) {
   alert("jQuery is loaded");
} else {
 // jQuery is NOT loaded.
}
</script>
```

Comment: The jquery is loaded. that you for the tip on the space, I removed it however the slideshow is still not playing.

Comment: I believe I need this @Bob Kruithof

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us the contents of includes/javascript.js?

Comment: I put up the includes.js and compress.js, it think the problem is more with the compress.js

Comment: Just to let you know the slideshow does actually work in firefox, safari, Chrome and IE8

Comment: Edited to include jQuery @Bob Kruithof

Comment: Looks like it was duplicate div names, go figure always something simple. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding document.ready around your jquery code e.g.

```
$(function(){
  //Jquery Code (place jquery code here)
  //Example only
  alert($('#wrapper').html());
});
```

AND/OR Make sure no white spaces are in jquery include src :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This? 
   $(function(){
 $('slideshow').style.display='none';
 $('wrapper').style.display='block';
 var slideshow=new TINY.slideshow("slideshow");
 window.onload=function(){
  slideshow.auto=true;
  slideshow.speed=5;
  slideshow.info="information";
  slideshow.thumbs="slider";
  slideshow.left="slideleft";
  slideshow.right="slideright";
  slideshow.scrollSpeed=4;
  slideshow.spacing=5;
  slideshow.active="#fff";
  slideshow.init("slideshow","image");
 }

Comment: $(function(){
    $('.rollover').hover(function(){
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
        $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
    }, function() {
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
        $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
    });
});
  alert($('#wrapper').html());
});
@Marc Uberstein

Comment: Try replacing window.onload with a document.ready. Let me know if it helps. What actually happens in IE6 and IE7?